# friendly SEO urls with sunspot and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

How can create SEO friendly url using using sunspot?

I want to convert a search from this:

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurant?utf8=&search=newyork
```

To something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/restaurant/newyork
```

Answer (score 0):

router:

```
match '/restaurant/:q' => 'restaurants#search'
```

controller:

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @search = Restaurant.search do
      keywords params[:q]
    end
    @restaurants = @search.results
  end
end
```

Submitting the form in such a way as to generate that URL is a little more at your design discretion. You may need to use some Javascript to intercept the default submit action to craft and redirect to a custom URL.